# Java :String replace to convert time

Tags: android, string, time, str-replace

I'm trying to convert time that is stored in a  database as type string and print it in the appropriate format. I tried using **.replaceAll**. This resulted in 5:3 being replaced as 05:03 but also turned 17:3 into 0107:03. Does anyone have any suggestions on the correct approach?

```
  String moduleStartHour = (c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(database.KEY_MODULESTARTHOUR)));
    String moduleStartMinute = (c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(database.KEY_MODULESTARTMINUTE)));

    String newModuleStartHour= moduleStartHour.replaceAll("0", "00").replaceAll("1", "01").replaceAll("2", "03")
            .replaceAll('4', "04").replaceAll("5", "05").replaceAll("6", "06").replaceAll("7", "07").replaceAll("8", "08")
            .replaceAll("9", "09");
    String newModuleStartMinute= moduleStartMinute.replaceAll("0", "00").replaceAll("1", "01").replaceAll("2", "03")
            .replaceAll("4", "04").replaceAll("5", "05").replaceAll("6", "06").replaceAll("7", "07").replaceAll("8", "08")
            .replaceAll("9", "09");

    StringBuilder sb =new StringBuilder();
    sb.append(newModuleStartHour).append(":").append(newModuleStartMinute);
    String moduleStartTime = sb.toString();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if (moduleStartHour.length() == 1)
  moduleStartHour = "0" + moduleStartHour;

if (moduleStartMinute.length() == 1)
   moduleStartMinute  = "0" + moduleStartMinute;

StringBuilder sb =new StringBuilder();
sb.append(moduleStartHour).append(":").append(moduleStartMinute);
String moduleStartTime = sb.toString();
```

or if we use the StringBuilder for the entire process

```
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    if (moduleStartHour.length() == 1)
        sb.append("0");

    sb.append(moduleStartHour).append(":");

    if (moduleStartMinute.length() == 1)
        sb.append("0");

    sb.append(moduleStartMinute);

    String moduleStartTime = sb.toString();
```

Comment: thanks dymmeh but the time is stored as a string, so moduleStartHour is already a string as is moduleStartMinute

Comment: You can use the StringBuilder with your if statements too. :)